# How to find if all threads have completed without calling future.get?

Tags: java, multithreading, future

I need to know when all my threads have completed their work, but future.get(); stops all other activity untill threads have completed. So is there any other way to find out if all threads have completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `future.isDone()` to see whether the future has completed, without blocking.

Answer (score 2):

You also have the `Future.isDone` method at your disposal. You can poll those.

Answer (score 2):

I would add a task which waits for all the futures. This way your main thread is not blocked waiting for the results.

A gotcha with `isDone` is that it can return false if the task is cancelled.